# Why change ListView cursor to null on stop?

Tags: android, cursor, activity-lifecycle

I've been looking at examples of CursorAdapter implementations to make sure I'm doing everything right.

One thing I've noticed that I'm not doing is calling changeCursor(null) on my CursorAdapter in the Activity's onStop() handler.

```
mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
```

What is the purpose of this?  I'm willing to do it if there's a good reason, but I hate navigating to another Activity, backing up to this Activity, and seeing a blank screen for a second until a new Cursor is queried.

Comment: My guess is that so, when the cursor gets closed, it doesn't throw an exception when the adapter tries to query the cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of this?

As Falmarri suggests, it is so your `Cursor` is no longer tied to the adapter, and so you can `close()` the `Cursor` without problems. IMHO, it is not necessary to call `changeCursor(null)` in `onStop()`. Particularly if you manage your `Cursor` (`startManagingCursor()` on `Activity`), Android will take care of the `Cursor` for you with respect to the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I am not having the Activity manage the Cursor.  I've essentially copied this: http://apps-for-android.googlecode.com/svn-history/r77/trunk/RingsExtended/src/com/example/android/rings_extended/MusicPicker.java